# Algorithm to simplify an SQL query over many combinations of values

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have a set of data you want to query from a database table based on two or more columns and you have various combinations of values from those columns to query over.

For example, with these combination

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 2
B 3
B 4
C 2
C 3
C 4
C 5
```

the simplest automated way to write the query would be

```
...WHERE column1=A AND column2=1
OR column1=A AND column2=2
OR ...
```

This is accurate, but verbose.

Another approach would be to choose one list and group by that.

```
...WHERE column1=A AND column2 IN (1,2,3,4)
OR column1=B AND column2 IN (2,3,4)
OR column1=C AND column2 IN (2,3,4,5)
```

This can also be pretty verbose if the lists are large.

What I'm looking for is a good, programmatic/algorithmic way to simplify this to something more optimal, like

```
...WHERE column1 IN (A,B,C) AND column2 IN (2,3,4,5) AND NOT (column1=A AND column2=5)
OR column1=A AND column2=1
```

Realistically, I guess I'm looking for the shortest string representation, but rather than worry about the lengths of column names or values or the other code in between, I'd be more than satisfied with a way to minimize the number of times that values have to be printed, or something along those lines.

The given example is for two columns, but I would like to find an approach that can generalize to more columns.

It also doesn't have to be perfect. Pretty good is good enough for me.

Comment: You probably should say what you are trying to do as this sounds like an x/y problem. In any case, it appears rather vaguely defined. At first, it sounds like you want all the combinations of the two columns, but then later on you start introducing `but not where...` conditions. Nobody can programmatically derive these cases to exclude for you. Finally, why not just query for everything in the table. If you query for "All Cases" that will just be "Everything" ... so why the need for combinations?

Comment: @topsail the combinations are given, and I want to query only for rows with those combinations, as shown in the example queries. The NOT in the last query is there because the part before that includes the A/5 combo, which is not in the given list,  so it has to be excluded. I just used that as an example of one way you might simplify the expression.

Comment: @topsail you might be right about it being an x/y problem though, at least sort of. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me sooner that, in most cases at least, I should be able to build a join query instead, but for my purposes, I can't guarantee that that's an option because the source data might be from another database. So the question still has value for me.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you would just join on the given list then. It's hard to say what to do you if are querying a another database that has different data. You will need to provide more information - an example of the new problem.

Comment: In not sure what's confusing you. The "new problem" to which you're referring is the one spelled out in the question, complete with examples. I just don't say that the data is from some other table, because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, well you would just join on the list, then. Why does that not work?

Comment: I've been thinking in terms of joining on tables, which can't be joined across databases (to by knowledge, and certainly not across dialects). And the source of the data isn't always accessible anyway, but now that you mention it, I could probably load the given data into a temporary table and join on it that way.

Comment: @rybai I strongly recommend the temp table approach.  You can also use indexes in a way that straight SQL logic can't.